# CSS - resize - remove javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know how to.. 
Remove a  using CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1600px) {
    #shout {
        display: none;

    }
}
```

But I want to know how to remove a javascript with resize if possible?
With javascript I mean this:

```
<script src="assets/js/minimap.js"></script>
```

... The minimap script also has a css file , called minimap.css. So I could manipulate that file too if needed.

Comment: You want to disable the script on window resize if the viewport width after resize is less than some dimension?

Comment: yes. i want to get rid of the minimap if my screen is small as an ipad. 

=)

Comment: The solution you accepted doesn't need to be in javascript - that can just be a simple CSS media query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    $(window).resize(function(){

    if(window.innerWidth<400){
    $('#abc').css({'display':'none'});
    }
    else 
    $('#abc').css({'display':'block'});
    }).resize();
```

```css
#abc{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:#545454;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc"></div>
```

Alternatively using javascript:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize',checkResize)
function checkResize(){
if(window.innerWidth<400){
document.getElementById("abc").style.display="none";
}
else
document.getElementById("abc").style.display="block";

}
checkResize();
```

```css
#abc{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:#545454;
}
```

```html
<div id="abc"></div>
```

Comment: ty for helping me :)